# Create new dataframe column where cell value indicates animal type

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Suppose that I have the following dataframe called `pet_stores` that consists of the number of cats and dogs per location of a pet store franchise

```
    Dog   Cat   City
0   5     11    NYC
1   4     1     San Francisco
```

How can I transform this dataframe such that instead of having separate Dog and Cat columns I have a single column called `animal_type`? I want the following result:

```
    animal_type Count   City
0   Dog         5       NYC
1   Dog         4       San Francisco
2   Cat         11      NYC
3   Cat         1       San Francisco
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt):

```
>>> df.melt('City', var_name='animal_type', value_name='Count')
            City animal_type  Count
0            NYC         Dog      5
1  San Francisco         Dog      4
2            NYC         Cat     11
3  San Francisco         Cat      1
```

Without `melt` and index manipulation:

```
>>>  df.set_index('City').rename_axis(columns='animal_type') \
       .stack().rename('Count').reset_index()
            City animal_type  Count
0            NYC         Dog      5
1            NYC         Cat     11
2  San Francisco         Dog      4
3  San Francisco         Cat      1
```

Use `sort_values` to change the order of rows.